# regex to find tags/attributes are inside html code

Tags: c++, regex, pcre

I want to find certain common html tags/attributes

```
<a href="xyz">this is an example of an href</a>
```

I want to find the first instance of "href" as it is used inside html code, but not the second instance as it is simply html.

I could try and look for code inside "< ... >" delimiters, but there are 2 problems, most browsers will allow the '<' even if it should have been "gt;"

```
the letter A is < than the letter B
```

or

```
<a name="24 is > than 12">this is an example of an href</a>
```

So I can I safely look for attributes inside html even if it is not always 100% properly formatted code using Regex?

Comment: keep this in mind http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: I am _not_ looking for an html parser, I just want to look for a word, "href" and tell if it is used inside an html tag or if it is just used as text.

Comment: Also see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/597607

Comment: As mentioned, I am not trying to parse html as such, I want to be able to find a specific word inside a tag and exclude those that are not.

Comment: And in order to find this you parse the html.

Comment: Yes, I guess you are right.
I am just not sure if you need a full blown parser to search for tags vs 'plain text'

Answer (score 0):

The regex `<\s*a\s+(?:\w+\s*=\s*(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*')\s+)*href\s*=\s*(?:"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)')`

will match strings # 1, 4, 5, 7, 8

```
1: <a href="xyz">this is an example of an href</a> 

2: <a name="24 is > than 12">this is an example of an href</a>

3: <a name="24 is > than 12">this is an example of an href="xyz"</a>

4: <a href="xyz" name="24 is > than 12">this is an example of an href</a>

5: <a name="24 is > than 12" href="xyz">this is an example of an href</a>

6: <a name="24 is > than 12 href='xyz'">this is an example of an href</a>

7: <a name="24 is > than 12 href='xyz'" href="xyz">this is an example of an href</a>

8: <a name="24 is > than 12 href='xyz'" href="xyz">this is an example of an href="xyz"</a>
```

Tested via [Regex Online](https://regex101.com/r/uI5fR6/1).

In case of using `'` quotes you have to use the second match group (`matches[2]`).